# RxJS what is mirror?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I often see in the RxJS the following term:

> **mirrors** the source Observable

What they mean by saying mirrors?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_(programming)

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting downvotes. Something is wrong with my question?

Comment: This is not a site to ask about english language. Got you an upvote though

Comment: I'm not asking about the English; I'm asking what is mirroring on the tech side.

Comment: The tooltip says: "_This question does not show any research effort; ..._" Where is your research part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirrors the source observable means the output (of a particular operator, for example) is the same as the source observable (under some conditions).

For example [retryWhen()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen) mirrors the source observable if no errors thrown in the operation.This means the result is the same as the source observable when there is no errors.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.